# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, socket io, redis

Tags: laravel, socket.io, port, node-redis

I am having problems starting the node server.js file because the port that it wants to use is taken by Laragon Apache which allows me to open the project in the browser.

This is the node server.js file :

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');

server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("client connected");
    var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
        console.log("mew message add in queue "+ data['message'] + " channel");
        socket.emit(channel, data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        redisClient.quit();
    });

});
```

When I start it in cmder with node server.js is can not use the port.Node server.js command in cmder:

```
client connected
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1087:14)

D:\laragon\www\canvas-messenger\nodejs (master)
node server.js
```

With Laragon Apache on the browser console looks like this,

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

and

```
GET http://localhost:8890/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1524944736161-36 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

error continuously repeting itself because the node server.js can not run I guess.

I have tried installing redis and socket io with laravel echo server, giving them different ports that would allow them to work with out making problems to each other but the functionality of the Chat in the browser would still be lost.

Thank you for reading !

Comment: Please, avoid images of code. Put the relevant code in the question description itself.